# iPhone login screen number pad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

I am writing an app and I want to show the login screen just like in iPhone where you have to enter 4 digit code to login. What's the best way to do this? Is there a UIView that comes with the SDK or will i have to design my own keyboard
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CocoaControls is an excellent site to browse Cocoa & Cocoa Touch custom UI components:

**http://cocoacontrols.com/**

You can use **PINView**: http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/pinview

[image]

Or **KVPasscodeViewController**: http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/kvpasscodeviewcontroller

[image]

Or **JSLockScreen**: http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/jslockscreen

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Previously answered at [steps / idea for a Iphone passcode like custom interface for Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785147/steps-idea-for-a-iphone-passcode-like-custom-interface-for-application): this option from that question looks promising (see https://github.com/vikingosegundo/KeyPad).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this latest source code to do so. URL is https://github.com/abury/ABPadLockScreen

Hopes this will help you.